# On which layer openflow protocol works?

Tags: wireshark-dissector, openflow

i am new to the openflow protocol ,i want to know in which layer openflow protocol works.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OF protocol is sent over TSL/SSL, or pure unencrypted TCP, between controller and device so it's a layer 7 application protocol, or TCP/IP model application layer.

As you marked it the Q with wireshark-dissector: [dissector](http://wiki.wireshark.org/OpenFlow)

You can see a screenshot of it here: [picture from wireshark](http://archive.openflow.org/downloads/screenshot-openflow-dissector-2008-07-15-2103.jpg)

Comment: @shiva please confirm the answer if you find it acceptable